# How to perform 1 step ahead forecasts with a VAR function

Tags: forecasting, vector-autoregression

Say I am given the parameters of a VAR (2) function with two variables. How would I use this information to perform a 1 step ahead forecast?

Example of what I would have is...

$A_t= 1.5 - 0.5A_{t-1} +0.2A_{t-2} - 0.35B_{t-1} - 0.1_{t-2}$

B(t)= 1.1 - 0.65B(t-1) +0.3(t-2)- 0.23A(t-1) +0.09A(t-2)

Sorry for the format, I don't know how to do subscripts on this site.

Comment: Welcome to CV.  You can use $\LaTeX$ for subscripts and other math. I edited the first formula for you, so you can see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

It´s quite simple:

Your model uses 2 variables with 2 lags. Each Equation gives you the actual forecast when you include the "old data".

E.g.

$A_{t-1}=1$

$A_{t-2}=2$

$B_{t-1}=3$

$B_{t-2}=4$

$A(t)= 1.5 - 0.5*1 +0.2*2 - 0.35*3 - 0.1*4 = -0.05$

$B(t)= 1.1 - 0.65*3 +0.3*4- 0.23*1 +0.09*2 =  0.3$

(You can add a formula in Latex format by using `$insert formula$`)